# AngularJS - ngModel bound dropdown value changes visually while variable doesn't

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown list:

```
<select
   ng-model="filter.country"
   ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countries"
   ng-change="broadcast()">
   <option value="">All Countries</option>
</select>
```

`$scope.countries` is initially populated by a service, and then another dropdown change event would limit the values of `$scope.countries` by calling the service again, passing by the other dropdown's selected item.

The issue here is when `$scope.filter.country` is already bound to a value (other than the default value) and `$scope.countries` gets updated to a new list that doesn't include `$scope.filter.country`'s value. I can see countries dropdown reverting back to its default option "All Countries", however `$scope.filter.country` remains as it was.

Any ideas about this scenario? Shouldn't `$scope.filter.country` get updated back to the default value?

**Update:** Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUm7y/)

**Update:**

Just to illustrate this, here is a screenshot from the fiddle:
[image]

This does look like a bug to me, I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7736) for it.

**Update**: This has been addressed and [fixed](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular.js/commit/2d0a0a51d914d9b310c5d9f908590cad6c3b49e6) by angularjs team; [demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xySkDHjCmr3U56SRhbIm?p=preview).

Comment: perhaps a fiddle we can play with?

Comment: @Ronnie added a fiddle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The behavior you see is exactly how double-binding should work:

Most developers have a "feel" for double-binding more than an understanding. The "feeling" is that any visual change to a model-bound input  results in a model change.

But any developers who have tried mode-binding a JQuery date picker will attest to this phenomenon: ***The JQuery Date-Picker will not update an angular model bound to same input.*** In other words, picking a date through ***JQuery*** does not register with any AngularJS events.

Similarly, pasting values into model-bound inputs ***usually*** does not result in the model being updated.

### Analyzing your case:

You have changed the list of options for a model bound drop-down. As a result, the displayed option reverts back to default --> because the model-bound value is not a relevant choice.

Angular's `ng-model` doesn't care about the "options list" for your drop-down. The framework is waiting for some event that will cause it to run through the digest cycle and absorb a change of value picked. Even though something has "appeared" to change, this is an illusion or loop-hole depending on how you see it.

***For a drop-down (select element), a change event is a "click" on an option.***

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with that in the past. It took me a good while to fix.

Try replacing your select by:

```
<select ng-model="changeMe" ng-options="d as d for d in dummyValues" ng-change="changeMeChange(); filter.country = undefined">
    <option value="">Change Me</option>
</select>
```

adding the "filter.country = undefined" to your ng-change should reset the value of your model.

Hopefully that will sove your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the contents of the countries select is independent of the value of changeMe, then two-way binding won't help us here. Instead, we have to make the change manually as follows:

```
$scope.changeMeChange = function () {

    // this or a $scope.$watch for independent values in the changeMe drop down menu
    if ($scope.filter) {
        $scope.filter.country = null;
    }

    $scope.countries = [
        {
            "code": "MX",
            "name": "Mexico"
        }
    ];
};
```

If the the values in the changeMe select can be used to filter the country select and thus make the country select dependent upon the change me select, then we can use a filter as follows:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function FilterCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [
        {
            "code": "KW",
            "name": "Kuwait"
        },
        {
            "code": "US",
            "name": "USA"
        },
        {
            "code": "MX",
            "name": "Mexico"
        }
    ];

    $scope.dummyValues = ['MX'];


    $scope.changeMeChange = function() {
        $scope.countries = [
            {
                "code": "MX",
                "name": "Mexico"
            }
        ];
    };
};

<select ng-model="changeMe" ng-options="d as d for d in dummyValues" ng-change="changeMeChange()">
    <option value="">Change Me</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="filter.country" ng-options="country.code as country.name for country in countries | filter: { code: changeMe} ">
    <option value="">All Countries</option>
</select>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUm7y/7/) using the filter approach as it seems the more likely use case. If you want your users to have access to the complete list of countries if no change me option has been selected, then a [Custom Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) is the way to go.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-model is binded to the scope variable called `filter.country`. When you update the ng-options values, it doesn't trigger the change that would update `filter.country`. It's a separate and unrelated variable at this point. So, there is no implicit bound connection. Only on selection of the list, the selection field is updated.

Though you can easily reset the select model from where you call the service  or include a `$watch` on the options to reset the ngmodel value.

```
    $scope.$watch('countries', function() {
        //reset the model here
    });
```

Comment: Since the dropdown is bound to a variable via `ng-model` which indicates the selected item and the actual selected item is being changed (visually), it kind of makes sense for that variable to get updated, doesn't it?

Comment: Though i have the same opinion as of you i guess there might be a valid reason why this was created as such. I would like to here from some pros in the community

Answer (score 0):

```
            <table>
                <tr ng-init="states()">
                    <td>State</td>
                    <td><select ng-model="selectedState" data-ng-change="cities1()" data-ng-options="state.Id as state.Name for state in states" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td><select ng-model="selectedCity" data-ng-options="city as city for city in cities" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

.JS file contents -

```
$scope.cities = function () {
    $scope.working = true;
    $scope.title = "Loading Cities...";
    $scope.cities = [];
    $scope.queryDisabled = true;
    var stateId = $scope.selectedState;
    if (stateId) {
        $http.get("/api/city", { params: { "stateId": $scope.selectedState } }).success(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.cities = data;
            $scope.title = "Displaying Cities...";
            $scope.working = false;
            $scope.queryDisabled = false;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.title = data + status;
            $scope.working = false;
            $scope.queryDisabled = false;
        });
    }
    else {
        $scope.cities = [];
    }
};

$scope.$watch($scope.selectedState, function () {
    $scope.cities1 = $scope.cities;
});

$scope.cities1 = $scope.cities;
```

I don't know the reason why it is so and how it works, but I have to create a copy of the cities variable as cities1. Assign cities1 from cities iself, then use cities1 on State combo ng-change event and cities on City combo ng-model directive.
ng-click doesn't seems the right replace of ng-change. Child combobox contents should change when selected item is changed in Parent (State) combo, and not when someone just click on Parent combo.

Comment: Read the latest update on my question; the issue has been addressed and fixed in the new release of angularjs.